# Getting count of same fileds in Table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
1)question  
2)options
3)answers
```

Table 1 contains list of multiple choice questions. Table 2 contains multiple choices for the question.

Consider an example, I have the question "Which game do you like most?"

It is stored in table 1 with id 1. For this question there are 3 choices in table 2; as "cricket", "football", "tennis" with ids 1,2 & 3.

When a user answer this question the question id, and option id are stored to the third table as if he select football, entry in table 3 is question id and option id.

If another user select same option new entry is stored in table 3.

My need is that I want to get the count of each options in table 3.

Consider 10 users select cricket, 15 users select football, no user select tennis, so I need count as 10,15,0 with its corresponding option id

Table name: questions

```
--------------------------------
| id |      question            |
--------------------------------
|  1 | which game u like most   |
```

---

Table Name: options

```
------------------------------------------------
| id |  qid  |         option_name               |
------------------------------------------------
| 1  |   1   |          cricket                   |
------------------------------------------------
| 2  |   1   |          football                  |
------------------------------------------------
| 3  |   1   |          tennis                    |
------------------------------------------------
```

Table Name: answers

```
--------------------------------------------
| id | qid | optionId                       |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1   | 3                              |
---------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1   | 3                               |
----------------------------------------------
| 3  | 1   | 2                               |
----------------------------------------------
```

The above table means that, 2 people choose tennis, 1 people choose football and no one choose cricket. So I need result table as

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id | question                | option_name | count |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | which game u like most  | cricket     |   0   |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | which game u like most  | football    |   1   |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | which game u like most  | tennis      |   2    |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I tried, I didnt get the count for cricket, because no one selected cricket.I must get count of cricket as 0. Can any one help me solve the issue?
My sql code is

```
SELECT count(an.optionId) count , op.option_name, q.question from
questions q, options op, answers an where q.id=1
and  q.id=op.qid
and op.id=an.optionId
group by q.question, op.option_name
```

Comment: Seriously? Do you really think we would be able to help you with this little information ?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Akshay If you think a question is unclear, or incomplete, consider using your vote accordingly.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete information. Now I have added the detailed need. Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

okay for instance, i will try to assume your situation;

3 tables:

1. **question**(question_id, question,..)
2. **question_option**(question_id,option_id,option,..) note: question_id is fk
3. **user_answer**(question_id,option_id,..)

   ```
   select count(ua.option_id) count, qo.option,
   q.question_name 
   from question q, uestion_option qo, user_answer ua
   where q.question_id = ua.question_id
   and q.question_id = qo.question_id
   and qo.option_id = ua.option_id
   group by q.question_name, qo.option
   ```

Comment: Please dont ask more questions in an answer. Wait until your rep is high enough to comment.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by asking more questions?

Comment: you edited your answer. You asked a question at the end of it which you should not do. Also, please dont 'try to assume' the users situation. Once again, ask for clarity in a comment.

Comment: Eric it was not a question! i was trying to give a sample of the output table, but missed to format it! so all rows was in one line!
ex:
count question  option 3  ok was it okay?

Comment: its ok buddy, its not the end of the world, im just providing suggestions for your posts on a go forward to better improve them.

Comment: Hi Amr Hamza, your code is working , but my need is that , I want to get the count of each option  for a question. The above query only gives count for option that was selected by a user. If one option is not selected, I need its count as zero. can u plz help to solve this?